# How to reduce Checkers to P and NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, board-games

NxN Checkers where both players are playing to win is [EXPTIME complete.](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/cgt/hard.html)

If we fix NxN to be 8x8 and prepare a very large lookup table then it can be solved in constant time and space.

How to formulate Checkers to make it P and NP-complete? (2 different formulations)

Note: I am interested in usual competitive Checkers. Not 'Lose-in-1 Checkers in NP-complete.'

Comment: Just curious: how can it be P-complete if its size is a fixed constant? I am really noob regarding P- completeness and complexity in games in general

Comment: @VashTheStampede This statement in the question is wrong; if it can be solved in constant time and space it is not P-complete.

Comment: You are right. I have fixed the question. I just wanted to say that it is a subset of P